# How to assign IP address to server before windows login

Tags: c#, networking, udp

I have two servers on the same local network 192.168.10.#; the main server is set to 192.168.10.5 (IP-1) and it is running a c# application that UDP communicates with some network devices; the other server is the backup of the main one, and it is 192.168.10.6 (IP-2) but the c# application is not running. 
On both servers is running a task and its main purpose is to set the IP of the server to IP-1, with a netsh script, if there is no IP-1 server in the netwwork and then run the main c# application, or set the server to IP-2, if IP-1 already exists.

The problem is:
if one of the server shuts down with the IP-1 address assigned, the other one immediately gets the IP-1, but when the other server turns on again it gives me an IP conflict. So I need to start the server with a third IP addr IP-3 before it connects to the local network, and then configure it , depending on what is running.

I have this problem because the UPD devices need a remote IP address to communicate with and the server backup must be automated.

(sorry for my bad english)

thank you guys.

Comment: Usually, you would have a heartbeat on either separate network interfaces where the two servers are directly connected to each other, or the servers have secondary network addresses (probably not routed) on the existing network that are only used for the heartbeat.

Comment: I will search some information on how to do that, I really like this solution! But what if the IP address should be set on a virtual machines running on the server? the heartbeat must be of the physical one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the two servers needs its own IP that is not shared with anyone else.  That way, when a server starts up, there is no IP conflict.  Then the script that checks for the existence of the shared IP (which is difference from the IPs of each of the two servers) can run without issue.

For example, one server has IP-1 and another server has IP-2.  Then one of the servers will bring up IP-3 and start the C# application which binds to IP-3.  So IP-3 would be a virtual IP on the same physical interface as IP-1 or IP-2.

Comment: So in this way I should need a virtual IP address created by the c# application itself? will it work with external phisical devices? or should I add it to the IP addr list of the IPV4 config?

Comment: Ok I adopted that solution thank you! plus if can be of any interest, a friend of mine just told me  that with gpedit.msc you can run a script at the server startup, in this way you can set the IP address before the server connects to the network!

Answer (score 0):

you can try with  Virtual Interface and assign one primary ip address and multiple Multiple secondary IP Addresses.